# Writing contents of a JTable to a file

Tags: java, io, jtable

I cannot seem to manage to complete this functionality. I need this to write out to a text file.

My JTable is populated when a query is run, the query results then populate the JTable. Now with the results users of the program have the option of writing the contents of the JTable to a text file.

The output file is to have the column headings running along the top of the text file then the returned query data underneath it.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Cool, did you have a question or were you just sharing that with us?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Getting Header values added part of the code

Other than writing to a file, you can use the following..

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
int row,column,header;

// Write Header
for(header=0;header<JTable.getColumnCount;header++)
{
    //buffer.append(JTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(header).getHeaderValue(); -- This is not needed
    buffer.append(JTable.getColumnName(header);
    buffer.append(',');
}
buffer.append('\n');
// Write cell data
for(row=0;row<JTable.getRowCount();row++)
{
    for(column=0; column< JTable.getColumnCount();column++)
    {
        buffer.append(JTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column));
        buffer.append(',');
    }
    buffer.append('\n');
}

// Write the buffer to a file
```

Comment: as OP requested with TableHeader too, edit and add loop for that

Comment: I'm sorry. Wouldn't getRowCount and getColumnCount include the header too? If so, how do we intend to do that?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < (table.getColumnCount()); i++) { 
buffer.append(String.valueOf(table.getColumnName(i)) + "\t"); // or separator ('.') }
buffer.append('\n');

Comment: Just now added a different code to put the hand around the neck to touch the nose. :-) I'll add this too..

Comment: hmmm you forgot adds buffer.append('\n'); that's create new line before JTable contents, but there are some potential problem with combining TableView and TableModel, my bad, that I send TableHeader from TableView not from TableModel as shows your Code, because TableView should be 1) Sorted <nothing to do with header> 2) TableColumn removed from View 3) reordering TableColumns if is allowed 4) maybe another.......  just put everything from Table.getModel(...)